# Connectedness in metric spaces

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Let be (X,d), a metric space. For $ \epsilon>0$, and $p \in X$, we define $B_ \epsilon(p)=\left\{{x \in{} X: d(x,p)< \epsilon}\right\}$ and $C_ \epsilon(p)=\left\{{x \in{} X: d(x,p)\leq \epsilon}\right\}$.

To each of the following propositions, I need to do a proof if it's true or give a counterexaple if it's false:

1. If $C_ \epsilon(p)$ is connected, then $B_ \epsilon(p)$ is connected.
2. If $B_ \epsilon(p)$ and $B_ \delta(q)$ are connected, then $B_ \epsilon(p) \cap B_ \delta(q)$ is connected

I think that both propositions are false, but I could not find a counterexample.

Answer (score 2):

HINT: Let $X$ be the union of the closed line segments from $a=\langle 0,0\rangle$ to $b=\langle 0,5\rangle$, from $b$ to $c=\langle 1/2,5\rangle$, and from $c$ to $d=\langle 1/2,0\rangle$. Let $d$ be the metric that $X$ inherits from the usual Euclidean metric in the plane, and define a new metric $d'$ on $X$ by $d'(x,y)=\min\{d(x,y),1\}$. This space contains counterexamples. I’ve left one in the spoiler-protected block below.

> Consider $C_1(a)$ and $B_1(a)$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $X = S^1 \cup [-1,0) \cup (0,1]$ with the usual metric on $\mathbb{R}^2$ and consider $C_1(0), B_1(0)$.